# Find $\mathbb{P} [ \| Z+a\| \le r \mid \|Z \| \le r ]$ where $Z$ is an i.i.d. Gaussian vector

Tags: probability, probability-theory

How to find

\begin{align}
\mathbb{P} [ \| Z+a\| \le r \mid \|Z \| \le r ]
\end{align}
where $Z \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is an i.i.d. Gaussian vector?   Here $\| \cdot\|$ is the Euclidean norm. 
If the close form is difficult to get it would be interesting to see an upper bound that is asymptotically tight as $n\to \infty$.

If $\| a\| \ge 2r $ then the probability is zero.  So we have to assume that  $\| a\| \ge 2r $.

One can approach this question by using Bayes rule 
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P} [ \| Z+a\| \le r \mid \|Z \| \le r ]= \frac{ \mathbb{P} [ \| Z+a\| \le r , \|Z \| \le r ]}{ P[\|Z \| \le r ]},
\end{align}

Note that $P[\|Z \| \le r ]=1-\frac{\Gamma(n/2,r^2/2)}{\Gamma(n/2)}$.

So, the question boils down to finding the joint probability $\mathbb{P} [ \| Z+a\| \le r , \|Z \| \le r ]$.

As suggested in sketch of a proof by  @kimchi lover   we should define
\begin{align}
(R,S)=(\|Z+a\|, \|Z\|)= \left(\sqrt{ (Z_1+A)^2 +Q}, \sqrt{ Z_1^2 +Q}   \right)
\end{align}
where $Q$ is a chi-square distribution.  In this case
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P} [ \| Z+a\| \le r , \|Z \| \le r ]=\mathbb{P} [R \le r , S \le r ]= \int_0^r \int_0^r f_{R,S}(x,y)dxdy.
\end{align}

However, it is not very clear to me how to find the joint distribution  $f_{R,S}(x,y)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $\|v\|$ denotes the Euclidean length of $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$, you can use this method, involving a certain amount of calculus.  By the rotational invariance of mean-$0$ i.i.d. Gaussians,  you may as well assume $a$ is of the form $(A,0,\ldots,0)$, with $A\ge0$.  Now it is easy to express the joint distribution of the pair $(R,S) = (\|Z+a\|, \|Z\|)$ in terms of the independent r.v.s $Z_1$ and $\sum_{i>1} Z_i^2$. The former is $N(0,1)$ and the latter is chi-squared with $n-1$ degrees of freedom.  Your desired conditional probability is the ratio of two integrals, each over a 2-dimensional region.

ADDED, edited 17 July 2017.

Writing $R=\sqrt{(Z_1+A)^2+Q}$ and $S=\sqrt{Z_1^2+Q}$, where $Z_1$ is $N(0,1)$ and $Q$ is $\chi_{n-1}^2$, the numerator integral (for $P(R\le r, S\le r)$) is $$E \,P( R\le r, S\le r | Q) = E \,\,I_{Q\le r^2} P ( (r^2-Q)^{1/2}-A \le Z_1 \le (r^2-Q)^{1/2} | \, Q).$$  (Here $I_{Q\le r^2}$ is the indicator r.v. for the event $[Q\le r^2].$)
If $f$ denotes the $\chi_{n-1}^2$ density, the numerator integral is
$$ \int_0^{r^2-A^2/4}f(q) \left( \Phi( (r^2-q)^{1/2} - \Phi((r^2-q)^{1/2}-A) \right) \,dq.$$

(The upper range of integration encodes the condition that the intersection of the events $[(Z_1+A)^2+Q\le r^2]$ and $[Z_1^2+Q\le r^2]$ is non-empty. Conditional on $Q$, each of these events bounds $Z_1$ to an interval: $-\Delta -A \le Z_1 \le \Delta -A$ and $-\Delta \le Z_1 \le \Delta$, respectively, where $\Delta=\sqrt{r^2-Q}$.  The intersection is nontrivial when $\Delta-A \ge -\Delta$.  Then the intersection is $[\Delta-A \le Z_1 \le \Delta].$)

The denominator integral is $$ \int_0^{r^2} f(q) \left( \Phi( (r^2-q)^{1/2} - \Phi(-(r^2-q)^{1/2}) \right) \,dq.$$

These integrals are formally 1-dimensional, but the use of the $\Phi$ function can be considered as sweeping 2-dimensional integral dirt under the rug.

Comment: What is Maxwell's theorem? Also, it would be nice if you could fill in more details.

Comment: [Maxwell's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_theorem) asserts the rotational invariance of the multivariate gaussian distribution. It should be in everyone's toolkit.

Comment: Ok.  So, your when you do the rotation how is $A$ related to $a$? Also, can you write down the distribution of $(R,S)$?

Comment: The length of $a$ is unchanged by rotations, so $A=\|a\|$.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. What about the pdf of $(R,S)$?

Comment: Start by writing $R$ and $S$ in terms of $Z_1$ and $\sum_{i>1}Z_i^2.$ As I said, a certain amount of calculus is involved.

Comment: @kimchi lover: The rotation invariance of the distribution of $n$ i.i.d. standard normals is not hard to check. Maxwell's theorem is, in fact, a converse assertion and lies deeper. It states that if the law of $n$ i.i.d. random variables is rotation invariant, then the random variables must be normally distributed (and centered).

Comment: I have a added a comment based on your sketch of the proof. However, I can not find the joint pdf $f_{R,S}$.

Comment: I have added detail. As promised, it involves a certain amount of calculus.

Comment: Quick question about the intersection of events.  At the end when you intersect $-\Delta-A \le Z_1 \le \Delta -A$ and $-\Delta  \le Z_1 \le \Delta$, shouldn't you get   an event   $-\Delta  \le Z_1 \le  \Delta -A$. Which would be $\Phi(\Delta-A)-\Phi(-\Delta)$.  I think you are using $-\Delta-A \le Z \le \Delta$?

Comment: The intersection of $[-\Delta -A, \Delta-A]$ and $[-\Delta, \Delta]$ is empty if $\Delta-A<-\Delta$, and $[\Delta-A, \Delta]$ otherwise.  I have a mistake in the range of integration in my next-to-last displayed integral, which I'll fix now.  Thanks for the catch.